# How to translate "Muscle Memory" to chinese?

Tags: translation

I cannot find a perfect word to describe "记忆".
So any one can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Muscle Memory is `肌肉记忆` in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

记忆 = memory
Muscle memory = more exact is 肌肉的记忆
And how you want to describe of two words.

To describe these two words. you can. A sence of memory from the past that still remember in our life